# Truffle migrate: exited with an error (status 0): Please check that the transaction: satisfies all conditions set by Solidity `require` statements

Tags: solidity, truffle, truffle-migration

I'm learning to use Truffle for the first time, and when I run `migrate` in the Truffle Develop console, I get the following error:

[image]

1_initial_migration.js:

```
const FilePermissions = artifacts.require("FilePermissions");

module.exports = function (deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(FilePermissions);
};
```

This error is vague to me, so please let me know if more code or config info is needed.

Comment: Never saw this error before. Can you share the code of the contract? I am curious about what generates such an error.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by resetting 1_initial_migration.js to its default:

```
var Migrations = artifacts.require("Migrations");

module.exports = function (deployer) {
  // Deploy the Migrations contract as our only task
  deployer.deploy(Migrations);
};
```

and creating a new file 2_initial_migration.js with the contents from my original post.

This is because, according to [these](https://trufflesuite.com/docs/truffle/getting-started/running-migrations.html) docs about Migrations.sol, you "must deploy this contract inside your first migration in order to take advantage of the migrations feature".